# How to fetch PLC S7-300 serial hexdata

Tags: c#, java, plc

We have Siemens PLC S7-300 with Ethernet communication port.
Which type of java or other language coding available for getting the frame data of plc.?
this PLC communicate only with step-7 software.

This frame structure data also can store in xml of some text file so we can continuous send it to internet.

Please help me

Comment: Have you read the manufacturer's documentation ?

Comment: LIBNODAVE: http://libnodave.sourceforge.net. You can access S7 PLC data from C, C++, C#, Delphi, Pascal, Perl and VB.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3rd party libraries that allow that. At our company we are using [Accon AGLink](http://www.deltalogic.de/en/products/software/accon-aglink.html). It's a native library, but it also provides a .NET wrapper. The library is somewhat fast. You could also try [this one (indi.an PLCCom)](http://indi-an.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=65&catid=2&Itemid=71) which is managed, and not so fast, but it has a free version.

Alternatively you could try setting up an [OPC](http://www.opcfoundation.org/Default.aspx) server and read the PLC data using an OPC client, but they are somewhat expensive.

Comment: using this i get data in which format??? is it store on some file and send it to internet..or not.!!.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[Snap7](http://snap7.sourceforge.net)**, which is **written in C but with many wrappers and ports available**, including Python, Node.js, .NET, C#, Arduino, and one in Java called [Moka7](http://snap7.sourceforge.net/moka7.html), since you asked.

From the official documentation:

> *Snap7 is an open source, 32/64 bit, multi-platform Ethernet communication suite for interfacing natively with Siemens S7 PLCs. The
>   new CPUs 1200/1500, the old S7200, the small LOGO 0BA7/0BA8 and SINAMICS Drives are also partially supported.*

I'm assuming that your setup consists on an S7-300 CPU with a CP 343 communication module. To read data from the CPU, the system must be running an S7 server (configurable via **NetPro**, inside **SIMATIC Manager**, as explained in the [Siemens commissioning manual](http://extras.springer.com/2010/978-3-642-12014-5/CD_2/_Manuals/English/S7-CPs_for_Industrial_Ethernet.pdf)). The remote machine should be using the Snap7 client library.

The library includes functions to read different memory areas, such as the process inputs (I), process outputs (Q), *merkers* (M), timers (T), and counters (C), as well as general purpose data blocks (DBs). If the server is enabled, and the configuration is not restricted (for instance to a certain IP address) the client should have access by default to at least the I's, Q's and M's, as well as to some system properties (like the CPU model and the firmware version).

For your case in Java, **have a look at the Moka7 documentation**, which can be found in the same [download package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/snap7/files/Moka7/1.0.2/). There are several code examples to get started.

If successful, the `ReadArea` function will return hex data of the bytes you specified (i.e. the memory position to start reading from, and the number of bytes). As a remark, **remember that most Siemens PLCs are big-endian**, so you may have to make a conversion if you're reading memory areas that hold data in different types.